# Can I use the 2 lane MIPI DSI display port to connect a camera?

Tags: camera

I have a camera working fine when connected to the  `2 lane MIPI DSI camera port`. But I need to connect it to the  `2 lane MIPI DSI display port`. However when I connect it and check for detected cameras with

```
vcgencmd get_camera
```

I get:

```
supported = 1, detected = 0
```

How can I make it work?

I'm using raspberry 4 B with Raspbian 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Camera" port on the Raspberry is not a DSI (which stands for Display Serial Interface), but a CSI (Camera Serial Interface). While similar, they are electrically [different](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/r-pi-ffc-connectors) and cannot be used instead of each other:

### DSI

[image: DSI Connector]

### CSI

[image: CSI Connector]